Deneb in Power BI freezing
I am developing a visualization of Deneb in Power Bi. The visualization uses an arch. In order for the visualization to resize when the container is changed, I added coefficients to recalculate the dimensions. I couldn't change it with standard settings. Now, when changing the size of the visualization, Power Bi is freezed. Is it possible to bypass this? Is it possible to do it somehow with standard settings? I attaching the file with report.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JiQwrhxUdBNT6QCSq-8t-rowhbWScZJY/view?usp=sharing


Please report here: https://github.com/deneb-viz/deneb/issues

So, basically:
Remove the height and width properties (Deneb will patch these for you if absent).
Remove the resize: true configuration (Deneb will recalculate the view on resize anyway).

solution from here
